# RestClient.post Angular 7

Tags: angular, github

Estou tentando criar um post como esse, mais em angular 7:

```
    get '/callback' do
  # get temporary GitHub code...
  session_code = request.env['rack.request.query_hash']['code']

  # ... and POST it back to GitHub
  result = RestClient.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
                          {:client_id => CLIENT_ID,
                           :client_secret => CLIENT_SECRET,
                           :code => session_code},
                           :accept => :json)

  # extract the token and granted scopes
  access_token = JSON.parse(result)['access_token']
end
```

**Esta assim:**

```
getClient(session_code: any) {
    this.http.post("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", {
      "client_id": this.CLIENT_ID,
      "client_secret": this.CLIENT_SECRET,
      "code": session_code
    }, httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error", error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Mais esta dando erro[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou criando essa autenticação em angular, não encontrei nada pesquisando:
https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/basics-of-authentication/

Comment: Você tentou pelo Postman?

Comment: No postman funciona

Comment: Acho que a requisição pode estar diferente

Comment: alterei a requisição para o formato do postman, e mesmo assim da o mesmo erro.

Comment: da uma olhada nisso aqui https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e Da uma pesquisada  em cors

Comment: Mostra os detalhes do erro para ter uma ideia melhor.